# How can I get application.yml information from jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, yaml, gitignore

Build by integrating Jenkins with GitHub's public repository.

However, the application.yml file with important information does not exist in the repository because it is included in the gitignore file

How can I get application.yml information from jenkins?

Comment: If it's not in the repo where is it located?

Comment: @ycr because it is an important properties file, it is not uploaded to the github repository due to gitignore. When building in jenkins, I wonder how to automate it by including a property file stored local or elsewhere

Comment: I guess you could [add it as secret](https://devops.com/how-to-securely-manage-secrets-within-jenkins/) but I really wonder how „it is an important properties file“ is an argument for *not* making it part of the repository.